# Reading an HDF file outside a Docker container from a Python script inside a container

Tags: python, docker, hdf5

I have a Python script, python_script.py, that reads an HDF5 file, hdf_file.h5, on my local machine. The directory path to the files is

- folder1

  - folder2

    - python_script.py
    - hdf_file.h5

I have the following sample code:

```
from pandas import read_hdf
df = read_hdf('hdf_file.h5')
```

When I run this code on my local machine, it works fine.

However, I need to place the Python script inside a Docker container, keep the HDF file out of the container, and have the code read the file. I want to have something like the following directory path for the container:

- folder1

  - folder2

    - hdf_file.h5
  - docker-folder

    - python_script.py
    - requirements.txt
    - Dockerfile

I use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /project
COPY ./requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /project
CMD [ "python", "python_script.py" ]
```

I am new to Docker and am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to get a Python script inside a container to read a file outside the container. What commands do I use or code changes do I make to be able to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to use Docker for this, rather than, say, a Python virtual environment?

Comment: David, this code is a prototype for a final product that will be deployed on other systems. The source code cannot be visible to others, so I'm using Docker to hide the code. I concede that this might not be the best approach and am open to others, but I thought this might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use docker volumes (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Try the following:

```
docker run -v path/where/lives/hdf5/:path/to/your/project/folder/your_image your_docker_image:your_tag
```

Where the first part before the `:` refers to host machine and after, the container.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a question about the paths. I open a command prompt and cd into the directory folder1/docker-folder, where my Dockerfile and python script are located. I build a Docker image called my_image and the run the command docker run -v /Users/folder1/docker-folder:/project my_image   I get the error   python: can't open file 'python_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory    Can you tell my what i'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: I think that the problem is related with the CMD command in your docker file. This command gets executed before the volume assignment, so, your container cannot open the script because is not "inside" the container yet. Try to use an entry point script instead. (```docker run -entrypoint ./entrypoint.sh -v /Users/folder1/docker-folder:/project my_image ```). Where the entrypoint.sh is a bash script which just runs your python command.

Comment: I realize I made a mistake in my initial question, so I made a small edit to my original post. Without making any changes to my Python code or Dockerfile, I entered and ran the following command: docker run -v /Users/folder1/folder2/:/project/my_image my-image   With this command, the Python script starts to run, but I get the error FileNotFoundError: File hdf_file.h5 does not exist   Am I making some mistake in how I use the volume?